# UITextfield output to string

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.1

I can't figure out how to get the output of the textfield into a string to use with parse password reset method. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func resetPassword(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Password Reset", message: "Enter Email To Reset Password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    refreshAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { emailField -> Void in
    //TextField configuration
    emailField.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        emailField.placeholder = "Email Address On File"


}

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        println("Handle Ok logic here")

        PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(" ", target: nil, selector: nil)

    }))

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        println("Handle Cancel Logic here")
    }))

    presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

I need it so when the button is pressed whatever email they put in is sent to parse using he password reset method. Any help would be great!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [textFields](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertController/textFields) property of `UIAlertController`.

You can do that in two ways:

```
refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    var textField = (refreshAlert.textFields as Array<UITextField>)[0]
    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(textField.text, target: nil, selector: nil)

}))
```

Comment: I get a [AnyObject]? does not have  a member named  'firstObject' error

Comment: That did it thanks a million!!!! I was banging my head against the wall on this one.